# Как с помощью отношений Eloquent получить друзей пользователя зная только его идентификатор?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

У меня есть две таблицы:

**users**: id, username,email

**users_friends**: id, user_id, friend_id (friend_id ссылается на user.id)

С помощью QueryBuilder у меня прекрасно отрабатывает такой запрос:

```
return DB::table('users_friends')
                ->join('users', 'users_friends.friend_id', 'users.id')
                ->select('users_friends.friend_id as id','users.username', 'users.email', 'users.avatar', 'users.last_login')
                ->where('users_friends.user_id', $userId)
                ->get();
```

Однако как мне получить такой же результат, только с помощью отношений Eloquent?

Моя модель User:

```
public function friends()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Friends::class);
}
```

Моя модель Friends:

```
class Friends extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'users_friends';

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class,'friend_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: Ты ведь даже вопрос не прочитал внимательно, зачем сразу ссылаться на документацию? В вопросе и так приведён пример из раздела отношений многие ко многим, но вопрос немного сложнее того что написано в документации.

Comment: @АнатолийШевелев пример приведён не из раздела многие ко многим. Так как отношение составлено в корне не верно. Не может быть два "hasMany" метода. Один должен `иметь` внешний ключ, второй "принадлежать". Плюс в отношении многие ко многим учавствуют 3 таблицы. А тут 2 и то с нарушением указания таблиц.

Answer (score 1):

Сначала расскажу как просто делаются связи многие ко многим. В логику не вдавайтесь, тут просто в качестве примера. А после будет конкретный ответ как переделать вашу модель для друзей.

1. Модели должны назваться в единственном числе.
2. Модель для связующей таблицы не нужна. Плюс указывая как у вас выше, пропадает полностью модель `Friend`

   ```
   class Friends extends Model
   {
        use HasFactory;

        protected $table = 'users_friends'; // не надо так делать...

    ...
   ```
3. Прочтите из ссылке в комментарии как правильно делать отношения многие ко многим. Создаёте 3 таблицы users, friends и friend_user (последняя создаётся так в единственном числе плюс первое слово идёт то, первая буква которого раньше в алфавите, если хотите чтобы ларавель всё соединил за вас!)

Далее в `двух` моделях (3 не нужна) делаете `belongsToMany` и `hasMany` нельзя так как никто из этих двух сущностей не имеет внешнего ключа в своих таблицах.

```
class User extends Model
{

    public function friends()
    {
        // если таблица как у вас, её нужно указать явно вторым параметром
       // $this->belongsToMany(Friend::class, 'users_friends')
        return $this->belongsToMany(Friend::class);
    }
    ...
}

class Friend extends Model
{

    public function users()
    {
        // если таблица как у вас, её нужно указать явно вторым параметром
       // $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'users_friends')
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
    ...
}
```

Далее у каждой модели появятся соответственные методы

```
$user = auth()->user();
$friends = $user->friends; // получили друзей авторизованного пользователя

// или

$user->User::find($userId);
$friends = $user->friends;

//или 

$user->friends()->where('username', 'Вася')->get(); // получили всех друзей с именем Вася у пользователя
```

Но в вашей задаче все пользователи соединяются только между собой. Поэтому соедините пользователей с пользователями без доп моделей и т.д. Нужна только одна модель User

```
class User extends Model
{

    public function friends()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'users_friends', 'friend_id', 'id'); // проекта под рукой нет, должно заработать
    }
    ...
}
```

В результате будут работать те же функции что и выше привёл (а модель Friend удаляете)

```
$user = auth()->user();
$friends = $user->friends; // получили друзей авторизованного пользователя
```